Illogical paragraph in a textbook: is North Ireland considered a country despite not having a national animal?
This is from 'Cultural Crossroads 2 for Ukraine' by Virginia Evans (image).

Each country in the UK has its own national animal. England has the lion, Scotland has the unicorn and Wales has the red dragon. Northern Ireland has no national animal.

'North Ireland is not considered a country' seems to be the only logical inference if we try to logically link these sentences:

'Each country in the UK has its own national animal'
'North Ireland has no national animal.'

Northern Ireland is not a country because it does not have its own national animal, is it?

It's badly written.

From the ELL angle "North Ireland has no national animal" is incorrect, because 'North Ireland' isn't a place. And Northern Ireland isn't a country, but a province of UK. Having a national animal isn't relevant. Perhaps it's a question for SE Philosophy.

@WeatherVane - 'Northern Ireland is one of the four countries in the United Kingdom' - the British Council. 'Northern Ireland is one of the four countries of the United Kingdom' - BBC. 'Northern Ireland is a country in the United Kingdom' - UK Parliament (2024), 'Northern Ireland is a country of small farmers.' - George Forrest (Westminster MP for Mid-Ulster, Hansard 30 March 1962, )

What does this have to do with the English language, other than comprising English words?

@WeatherVane - I am old enough to remember hearing Captain Terence O'Neill taking about 'this country' (Ulster/NI) in a speech, and reading that James Callaghan called the Stormont 'Parliament' a 'glorified county council'.

For the avoidance of doubt, I support (and want) a thirty-two-county united Ireland.

Maybe a severed hand counts as an animal, although I don't recall it doing much after it was chopped off and thrown on a beach. The Irish hare is sometimes called the national animal of Ireland but I don't think it's something they make a lot of, in comparison to other national symbols, and not strongly linked to the North. Wikipedia claims the northern pike is the national fish of Northern Ireland but I'd never heard that before. All off-topic however.

I’m voting to close this question because North Ireland is not Northern Ireland, which the poster could have easily checked.

I’m voting to close this question because, as written, it doesn't seem to be about language but about logic. If you're concerned that you've misunderstood the language, please edit to explain more. Also, if possible, give more context. We can't be sure from this short passage exactly what the author intends.

I think the author's point is that the rule, "each country has its own national animal", doesn't work. There are only 4 examples -- England, Scotland, Wales, and Northern Island -- and of the 4, 1 does not follow the rule.
He phrases this rhetorically: If the rule is valid, than that means that Northern Ireland is not a country in the UK. This leads to two possible conclusions: either Ireland is not a country in the UK, or the rule is not valid. I think the author's point is that the rule is not valid, as the alternative conclusion is nonsense.

The statement does not mean Northern Ireland is not a country, although the wording could lead you to that conclusion. The reason NI is mentioned at all is because it is a country of the UK and it would be odd to leave it out without an explanation. Northern Ireland is regarded as a country within the UK, in the same way as Scotland is. Whether or not Northern Ireland should be the part of the UK is strongly contentious though and not something for this forum.
As Michael has said, it is badly written, and without the necessary knowledge you could easily draw the wrong conclusion.

This is a logic problem, not a language one. You can logically derive true statements from true premises, but starting from premises that aren't true in the first place doesn't allow you derive any truth at all.
If premises are true that 1) all UK countries have a national animal, and that 2) Northern Ireland does not have a national animal, we can derive that Northern Ireland is not a country of the UK.
This isn't true, however (Northern Ireland is a country of the UK), so there must be a problem with the premises. Either there are UK countries that do not have a national animal, or Northern Ireland has one, or both.
